# Multilevel glmer model predicting rare event -- Troubleshooting model convergence issues (degenerate Hessian)

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, lme4-nlme, multilevel-analysis, convergence

I have a massive dataset of social media posts. I want to assess whether several variables are related to a binary outcome. Because some people posted more than once, I am trying to account for this dependence by using a multilevel model (specifically, I am using lme4 in R).

I was unable to create a reproducible example from scratch, so a smaller version of the dataset is available [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1reTr7fzWweRDI7qXHJ-DBsfLnw1ULDfYHiwI6rl3rgU/edit?usp=sharing)

However, I am running into convergence issues, which I have tried to resolve by reading posts on StackExchange and CrossValidated. I have found a number of helpful posts and already tried troubleshooting by double-checking the data, scaling and centering predictors that aren't factors, and trying different optimizers/model estimation methods using allFit.

Here is my code:

```
mod_out <- glmer(outcome ~ x1 + x2 + ntoken_c + sent_c + (1 | id),
                  family = binomial(link = logit), data=samp,
                  control=glmerControl(optCtrl=list(maxfun=2000000)))
summary(mod_out)

Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace Approximation) ['glmerMod']
 Family: binomial  ( logit )
Formula: outcome ~ x1 + x2 + ntoken_c + sent_c + (1 | id)
   Data: samp
Control: glmerControl(optCtrl = list(maxfun = 2e+06))

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
   290.4    323.5   -139.2    278.4     1835 

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-1.0360 -0.0020 -0.0010 -0.0006  7.1598 

Random effects:
 Groups Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 id     (Intercept) 265.1    16.28   
Number of obs: 1841, groups:  id, 971

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept) -13.9851     2.4055  -5.814 6.11e-09 ***
x1            1.9822     1.2396   1.599 0.109814    
x2            0.9386     0.8767   1.071 0.284341    
ntoken_c      0.9144     0.3993   2.290 0.022037 *  
sent_c       -1.4462     0.4332  -3.338 0.000843 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
         (Intr) x1     x2     ntkn_c
x1       -0.124                     
x2       -0.164  0.295              
ntoken_c -0.096  0.030  0.119       
sent_c    0.221 -0.354 -0.259  0.029
optimizer (Nelder_Mead) convergence code: 0 (OK)
unable to evaluate scaled gradient
Model failed to converge: degenerate  Hessian with 1 negative eigenvalues

Warning messages:
1: In vcov.merMod(object, use.hessian = use.hessian) :
  variance-covariance matrix computed from finite-difference Hessian is
not positive definite or contains NA values: falling back to var-cov estimated from RX
2: In vcov.merMod(object, correlation = correlation, sigm = sig) :
  variance-covariance matrix computed from finite-difference Hessian is
not positive definite or contains NA values: falling back to var-cov estimated from RX
```

And the results of allFit:

```
$which.OK
                       bobyqa                   Nelder_Mead                    nlminbwrap 
                         TRUE                          TRUE                          TRUE 
                        nmkbw               optimx.L-BFGS-B nloptwrap.NLOPT_LN_NELDERMEAD 
                        FALSE                          TRUE                          TRUE 
    nloptwrap.NLOPT_LN_BOBYQA 
                         TRUE 

$msgs
$msgs$bobyqa
[1] "unable to evaluate scaled gradient"                                       
[2] "Model failed to converge: degenerate  Hessian with 1 negative eigenvalues"

$msgs$Nelder_Mead
[1] "Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 0.124815 (tol = 0.002, component 1)"

$msgs$nlminbwrap
[1] "unable to evaluate scaled gradient"                                       
[2] "Model failed to converge: degenerate  Hessian with 2 negative eigenvalues"

$msgs$`optimx.L-BFGS-B`
[1] "Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 0.00953883 (tol = 0.002, component 1)"

$msgs$nloptwrap.NLOPT_LN_NELDERMEAD
$msgs$nloptwrap.NLOPT_LN_NELDERMEAD[[1]]
[1] "Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 0.220821 (tol = 0.002, component 1)"

$msgs$nloptwrap.NLOPT_LN_NELDERMEAD[[2]]
[1] "Model is nearly unidentifiable: very large eigenvalue\n - Rescale variables?"


$msgs$nloptwrap.NLOPT_LN_BOBYQA
$msgs$nloptwrap.NLOPT_LN_BOBYQA[[1]]
[1] "Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 0.138928 (tol = 0.002, component 1)"

$msgs$nloptwrap.NLOPT_LN_BOBYQA[[2]]
[1] "Model is nearly unidentifiable: very large eigenvalue\n - Rescale variables?"

$msgs$nloptwrap.NLOPT_LN_BOBYQA[[3]]
[1] "Model is nearly unidentifiable: large eigenvalue ratio\n - Rescale variables?"



$fixef
                              (Intercept)       x1        x2  ntoken_c    sent_c
bobyqa                          -13.57502 1.608618 0.6200766 0.9026060 -1.368527
Nelder_Mead                     -14.04892 1.987066 0.9247450 0.9189074 -1.447382
nlminbwrap                      -13.89637 1.933577 0.9369676 0.9294457 -1.429027
optimx.L-BFGS-B                 -13.93577 1.942058 0.9448489 0.9324543 -1.433993
nloptwrap.NLOPT_LN_NELDERMEAD   -13.81772 1.792312 0.9097384 0.9072023 -1.428971
nloptwrap.NLOPT_LN_BOBYQA       -13.51245 1.776902 0.8955550 0.8985310 -1.381364

$llik
                       bobyqa                   Nelder_Mead                    nlminbwrap 
                    -139.2725                     -139.1914                     -139.1832 
              optimx.L-BFGS-B nloptwrap.NLOPT_LN_NELDERMEAD     nloptwrap.NLOPT_LN_BOBYQA 
                    -139.1836                     -139.1963                     -139.2188 

$sdcor
                              id.(Intercept)
bobyqa                              16.09118
Nelder_Mead                         16.36194
nlminbwrap                          16.06998
optimx.L-BFGS-B                     16.14636
nloptwrap.NLOPT_LN_NELDERMEAD       15.78800
nloptwrap.NLOPT_LN_BOBYQA           15.20833

$theta
                              id.(Intercept)
bobyqa                              16.09118
Nelder_Mead                         16.36194
nlminbwrap                          16.06998
optimx.L-BFGS-B                     16.14636
nloptwrap.NLOPT_LN_NELDERMEAD       15.78800
nloptwrap.NLOPT_LN_BOBYQA           15.20833

$times
                              user.self sys.self elapsed user.child sys.child
bobyqa                            20.15     0.01   22.51         NA        NA
Nelder_Mead                       31.86     0.02   34.29         NA        NA
nlminbwrap                        27.48     0.00   29.71         NA        NA
optimx.L-BFGS-B                  205.55     0.15  222.17         NA        NA
nloptwrap.NLOPT_LN_NELDERMEAD     25.53     0.02   27.48         NA        NA
nloptwrap.NLOPT_LN_BOBYQA         25.20     0.00   27.79         NA        NA

$feval
                       bobyqa                   Nelder_Mead                    nlminbwrap 
                          389                           661                            NA 
              optimx.L-BFGS-B nloptwrap.NLOPT_LN_NELDERMEAD     nloptwrap.NLOPT_LN_BOBYQA 
                          192                           500                           540 

attr(,"class")
[1] "summary.allFit"
```

The event I am trying to predict is very rare (~2% occurrence), and the majority of users did not post more than once (but some posted many times). Based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53034261/warning-lme4-model-failed-to-converge-with-maxgrad) I thought the problem might be that every user has the same value on the outcome, so there is no variance left to be explained by the fixed effects. The intercept seems extreme, as does the ICC (.98), which might support this explanation. But while this does appear to be the case for the majority, it is not true of everyone. However, if I drop the random effect from the model (which also makes it easier to apply a Firth correction for rare events), I experience no further issues.

I'm hoping that someone with more experience/statistical know-how can offer a clearer explanation of what is going on here. Is there a better way to identify whether this is, in fact, the problem? Is this sufficient rationale for dropping the random intercept? I came across some posts [e.g., here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38997371/glmer-warning-variance-covariance-matrix-is-not-positive-definite-or-cont) suggesting that convergence warnings can be ignored in some cases, but I am not sure that makes sense here (my estimates are not nearly as consistent across fits as in the example). Using the same dataset, I was able to successfully fit this model on other outcome variables, however, the outcomes occurred much more frequently.

Update: [This article](https://www.theanalysisfactor.com/wacky-hessian-matrix/) seems to support dropping the random intercept, since the warning messages may indicate that there isn't sufficient variation in the data for the random effect. However, I'm puzzled, because in my case, it doesn't seem like the intercept accounts for insufficient variance, but that it is accounting for almost all of the variance in the outcome?

Comment: You could plot the results based on various optimizers. If the results are consistent across optimizers, they would be more trustworthy. A function and a code-through is available at: https://pablobernabeu.github.io/2021/a-new-function-to-plot-convergence-diagnostics-from-lme4-allfit/